# How do I decide what is the best POV for my fantasy novel?

Tags: fantasy, viewpoint

How to go about determining what is the best POV to use for my fantasy novel?

Comment: Welcome to Writing SE! As it was originally written your question would likely have been closed as it was both extremely broad and heavily opinion-based. So I've edited your question to hopefully make it more inline with the format here, hopefully I haven't strayed too far from your original intent but if so you can always rollback my edit and make one of your own.

Answer (score 1):

There's no universal "best" POV for Fantasy (or indeed most genres), there can be a best for *your* particular story and that can be because of many factors.

If you need to keep the readers knowledge of the world and events the same as a particular character's then 1st person or 3rd person limited are the obvious choices, if you want the readers to know *more* than any one character (or even all the characters put together) then 3rd person omniscient makes sense.

If you're particularly strong at writing in a given POV then use that - it's better to have something well written in a given POV even if another might have suited the story better.

Comment: There's also third person objective, which is often called "roving camera" and would be limited to only that which can be observed (sight, sound, touch, taste, smell) by the reader... thoughts, feelings, and memories would not be allowed unless a character says it in dialog ("You can't just tell the audience how you feel.  That makes me so Angry!" to quote Futurama.).